# Implementing a void in swagger documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-node-express

I can't figure out how to implement a swagger (using a swagger-node-express project) function in node that just returns the response code

For instance for this swagger path:

```
/api/user/create:
x-swagger-router-controller: api
get:
  operationId: userCreate
  parameters:
    - name: username
      in: query
      description: The username of the user.
      required: true
      type: string
    - name: password
      in: query
      description: The password of the user.
      required: true
      type: string
    - name: email
      in: query
      description: The email of the user.
      required: true
      type: string
  responses:
    '200':
      description: OK
    '412':
      description: User already exists
```

I would like to send a return.

If I try

```
res.json(200);
```

or

```
res.sendStatus(200);
```

or even

```
res.sendStatus();
```

I get the error: Response validation failed: void does not allow a value

I get a parseerror in the swagger editor if I send

```
res.json()
```

And I get a void does not allow a value

I feel like I am out of options to try so I could really use some input.

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured out what was the problem for error:

> Response validation failed: void does not allow a value

When you have below lines in swagger.yaml

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
```

swagger does not understand what kind of response it should send. We need to explicitly specify schema of response as below to say valid response type.

```
responses:
  200:
    description: Success
    schema:
      title: reset
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when you just write a head and end the connection in the standard node way it works;

```
res.writeHead(code, message);
res.end();
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Still the old error:   

`{"message":"Response validation failed: void does not allow a value","code":"INVALID_TYPE","failedValidation":true,"path":["paths","/company/{companyName}","post","responses","200"],"originalResponse":"{}"}`